# Facebook gives me a "URL requested a HTTP redirect, but it could not be followed." but the browser has no issue following it, how can I fix that?

Tags: facebook

My URL is http://citynomads.com which redirects to http://www.citnomads.com and the browser follows the redirect perfectly well, but Facebooks linter is telling me it can't follow the link. I can't see why it's having an issue with this:

```
$ curl -i citynomads.com
HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
Server: nginx/1.0.8
Date: Sat, 28 Apr 2012 16:12:38 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 160
Connection: keep-alive
Location: http://www.citynomads.com/

<html>
<head><title>302 Found</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>302 Found</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.0.8</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Linter: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fcitynomads.com

How can I rectify that?

Comment: Because curl isn't a web browser and isn't going to follow redirects unless you specifically tell it to.

Comment: @BrianRoach The question is regarding why Facebooks linter (and by extension probably Facebook) is having an issue following the URL, not so much CURL. I'm CURLing to show what my server response is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is a FB linter bug. Your given linter link now works (has some other bizarre warnings, but not a failed redirect...)
This happened to me too, but posting the same url to facebook does generate a proper preview, so i'm guessing here...

Wouldn't be their first bug, nor the last...

HTH